# How do I describe all integers in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to write a basic program that spits out the English version of a number when the user inputs a numeral:

```
input = 44
output = fourty four
```

Is there a way to describe all integers?

Basically I want the execution to look something like:

```
number = gets.chomp

if number != (whatever the nomenclature is for integer)

puts 'Please enter a positive number'
```

or something to that effect.

Comment: `if !number.is_a?(Integer) || number < 0`?

Comment: It isn't clear whether you are asking how to describe all integers (question title) or how to determine if a string represents a positive integer (question body).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified the Fixnum class and added a method in_words. What I did is I broke each number up into groups of three, so 100000 turns into [100, 000] and 123456789 turns into [123, 456, 789] or 1543 turns into [1, 453] then I went element by element and named every number in the element and added the appropriate word, like hundred and thousand. If you have any questions I am happy to explain!

```
class Fixnum
  LOW = %w(zero one two three four five six seven
    eight nine ten eleven twelve thirteen fourteen
    fifteen sixteen seventeen eighteen nineteen)
  TWO_DIGIT = %w(ten twenty thirty forty fifty sixty seventy eighty ninety)
  BIG_NUMS = %w(hundred thousand million billion trillion)

  def in_words
    # Break up number into bytes with three bits each
    # Then turn each byte into words

    # Break into bytes
    number = self.to_s.reverse
    bytes = []
    num_bytes = (number.length.to_f / 3.0).ceil()
    num_bytes.times { |x| bytes << number[(x*3)..(x*3)+2].reverse }

    #puts bytes.reverse.join(",")

    # Turn bytes into words bit by bit
    word = []
    text = ""
    bytes.each_with_index do |byte, i|
      text = ""

      # First bit
      text = LOW[byte[0].to_i] if (byte.length == 3 && byte[0].to_i != 0) || byte.length == 1

      # Add hundred if 3 bits
      text += " hundred" if byte.length == 3 && byte[0].to_i != 0

      # Second bit
      if byte.length == 3 # Three bits
        if byte[1].to_i > 1 # Second bit greater than teens
          text += " " + TWO_DIGIT[byte[1].to_i + (-1)]
        elsif byte[1].to_i != 0 # Second bit not zero
          text += " " + LOW[byte[1..2].to_i]
        end
      elsif byte.length == 2 # Two bits
        if byte[0].to_i > 1 # Greater than teens
          text += " " + TWO_DIGIT[byte[0].to_i + (-1)]
          text += " " + LOW[byte[1].to_i] if byte[1].to_i != 0
        else # Less than twenty
          text += LOW[byte[0..1].to_i]
        end
      end

      # Third bit if three bytes and second bit > teens and third bit nonzero
      text += " " + LOW[byte[2].to_i] if byte[1].to_i != 1 && byte[2].to_i > 0 && byte.length > 2

      # Add trillion/billion/million/thousand
      text += " " + BIG_NUMS[i] if i != 0 && byte.to_i != 0

      word << text.strip if text.strip != ""

    end
    word.reverse.join(" ")
  end
end
```

Because I modified the Fixnum object, you can call this from any Fixnum e.g. `44.in_words`

EDIT: It looks like you might be trying to check input for integers. I would recommend making a function to handle that:

```
def check_input(i)
  if !(i =~ /^[0-9]+$/)
    puts "Sorry, that is an invalid input! Please try again"
    i = check_input(gets.chomp)
  end
  i.to_i
end
```

I think the best way to handle that is with regex (pattern matching). Basically your function checks if the input isn't a number, then it asks for input again. If it is a number, then the function returns the number. `/^[0-9]+$/` is the regex. `^` means start of the line and `$` means end of the line. `[0-9]` matches any digit zero through nine (as the Tin Man commented, you can also use `\d` to represent any digit and it is equivalent), and `+` means match the previous thing (any digit) at least once.

Comment: `[0-9]` is more easily/clearly written as `\d` and it's not necessary, or idiomatic, to use `return i.to_i`. Just use `i.to_i` instead.

Comment: You're right. I'll remove the `return` part, but since `\d` is equivalent I'll keep it. I think both are equally clear.

Answer (score 5):

You can do that with the `numbers_and_words` gem:

https://github.com/kslazarev/numbers_and_words

It supports languages other than english as well.

For example:

```
21.to_words
=> "twenty-one"

44.to_words
=> "forty-four"
```